# the hardness of Conjugacy Search Problem in matrix groups

Tags: cryptography, linear-groups

I learned that the Conjugacy Search Problem is considered as a mathematically hard problem to solve and can be used for cryptography.

Conjugacy search problem: Let G be a non-abelian group. Let g,h∈G be known elements such that h=xgx^(-1) for some x in G. Find the x.

can someone help me with its hardness in GL(n, Z_p), how to select n and p such that the Conjugacy Search Problem is hard in GL(n, Z_p)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.